# XC8's Microchip compiler long type doesn't go up 32bits value

Tags: xc8

I need a big number in my firmware, So i choosed long for the job.
In the microchip's documents the long type provides 4Bytes for use:
[image]

So i created this variable (timeCounter):
[image]

In a interrupt of 100us of timer2 this variable is incremented:
[image]

Problem:
The variable is unsigned long but when i plot his value the max value achieved is aproximately 32725! and the variable is SIGNED!!!!
image:
[image]

The code below shows a sizeof(unsigned long) equals to 4bytes...
[image]
[image]

I've already disabled the compiler optimizations.
Using PIC18f26k80.

=========================================================

code:

```
#include "main.h"

void main( void ){

char string[100];
unsigned long timeCounter;

setupHw();
initHw();
initSw();

while( true ){

    clearWDT();   


    /*============================================================================*\
     * Task3 (60s)
     * Processo...
     * Dependências:                  
    \* ===========================================================================*/
    if( f60s ){
        f60s = false;

        sprintf(string, "TimeCounter (60s): %d\n", timeCounter);
        txStringUart1(string);
       } // end da task2       
    }
}
```

Comment: Use text when excerpting code and console output, not screenshots.

Comment: [do **not** put code and text output in images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). Please edit the post and copy and paste the text here

Comment: -1 because of the above comments: please remove the pictures of text and replace with the actual text, and the downvote will be reverted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is not with your type but with the way you print it. In C 
`%d` format specifier is for `int`, not for `long`. For signed `long` you should use `%ld` instead, if your compiler supports it. For unsigned use `%lu`.

Comment: Please also specify to avoid many issue is better to use the c99 standard int library, with it's own formatter that makes very clear how many bit your are working with.

Comment: @Rique It is a standard C feature. If the compiler is standard-compliant it will have it. You should consult the docs and/or just try it.

Comment: @Rique Welcome to EE.SE. It is standard practice on this site to not immediately accept an answer, even if it is correct, to stimulate discussion and allow alternate answers a chance. Because you have already accepted an answer, the reputation bonus is gone and further discussion no longer has much incentive (the prize is gone). 24 hours is a reasonable wait time. You are free to up/downvote as you see fit with no time restrictions.